# Do all neurodegenerative diseases show up on an MRI scan?

Tags: neurology, mri, alzheimers, parkinson

Do all neurodegenerative diseases such as Parkinson's, Alzheimer's, etc. show up on an MRI scan?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neurodegenerative diseases are diagnosed on the basis of clinical symptoms (memory impairment for Alzheimer Disease/ bradykinesia, tremor and rigor for Parkinson Disease) +/- neuropsychological tests.

**The current role of neuroimaging in the diagnosis of neurogenerative diseases such as Parkinson Disease or Alzheimer Disease is mainly supportive**, it can be used

- to confirm a high suspicion for the disease (due to typical clinical
  presentation for example)
- to exclude possible other diseases when the clinical diagnosis is unclear

**None of the current dignostic criteria for AD or PD rely solely on neuroimaging studies.**

There are some signs on MRI scan which **may indicate** the presence of AD or PD but patients with advanced stages of the disease may show limited signs of the diseases on MRI.

In **AD**, patients typically present hippocampal atropy (craked walnut sign, see image below) or medio temporal atrophy. However, as hippocampal atrophy is also present with age, some age-specific criteria are needed to differentiate between a age-related hippocampal atrophy and an AD-related hippocampal atrophy. Other signs may be present such as white matter anomalies. But these signs do not correlate necessarily with the severity of the disease.

[image]

In PD, the role of MRI is very limited and is mainly used to help when a differential diagnosis for the symptoms is present. It can also help diagnosing between an idiopathic PD or a vascular PD for example (if signs of cerebrovascular diseases are present on the MRI).

Recently, **advanced techniques of neuroimaging** (non exhaustive list: functional brain imaging with [18F] FDG-PET, functional MRI (fMRI), perfusion MRI, SPECT, amyloid PET tracers (F18-florbetapir, F18-flutemetamol, F18-florbetaben) in AD and MR spectroscopy (MRS), magnetization transfer imaging, diffusion-weighted MRI, diffusion tensor MRI, and high-resolution imaging (eg, MRI at 7 Tesla) for PD) have been suggested to help in the diagnosis of AD and PD. However, most of the studies rely on a small number of patients so further studies including a larger sample size are needed to confirm the encouraging results.

*Sources:*

Wolk D et al. Clinical features and diagnosis of Alzheimer disease. UpToDate. October 2016. https://www.uptodate.com/contents/clinical-features-and-diagnosis-of-alzheimer-disease?source=machineLearning&search=alzheimer&selectedTitle=1~150&sectionRank=3&anchor=H406199175#H406199175

Chou K et al. Diagnosis and differential diagnosis of Parkinson disease. UpToDate. October 2016. https://www.uptodate.com/contents/diagnosis-and-differential-diagnosis-of-parkinson-disease?source=see_link#H17

for the picture: Ho M. and Eisenberg R. Neuroradiology signs. Alzheimer Disease, p19.